# UITableViewController with a UIPickerView sliding up the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UITableView where a cell needs to be filled in with a date by selecting it through a pickerview. Instead of pushing the pickerview onto the navigationController I would want to let it slide up halfway into the screen with the tableview still visible in the upper half of the screen. I've seen some apps doing this neat effect before but I don't see on how to accomplish this.

Anyone some helpful hints on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I did this a little while back and [asked about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870038/how-can-i-show-a-uidatepicker-instead-of-a-keyboard-when-a-user-selects-a-uitextf).*

I ended up doing exactly what the highest voted answer says: Put the UIPickerView in the same View as your other items and animate the sliding motion using UIView's [`beginanimation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/beginAnimations:context:) method.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was able to animate a view with a picker and a toolbar ontop of it into the same view, but can you tell me how to notify the parentview to slide the view back outwards the screen. In other words a way to let the parentview know he can dismiss the pickerview.

Answer (score 0):

Add a done button in your tool bar.  Add a new target/action to the button to call a method on the UIViewController that has your table view and picker controller.  Then have it animate the view back off the screen using a UIView animation block.